# Actualizar lista de un componente ya renderizado reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Alguien me puede responder una duda si es posible optimizar esta funcionalidad.

Estoy creando un aplicativo para una empresa, ellos requieren tener muchas tablas en su sitio web, para optimizar el tiempo de trabajo cree un componente de tabla que pueda ser usada por todo el sitio. Todos estos requieren distintos botones, modificar estado, editar el perfil, etc...

El usuario puede darle a un botón "crear" para añadir nuevos datos y al presionar este botón consultara los datos de la lista.

Pero si presiona "consultar" antes de crear consultara los datos sin la lista. La idea es no consultar la lista para no llenar la consulta con muchos datos y esta sea mas rápida, en caso de que el usuario solo quiera consultar los datos de la tabla.

El problema es que la forma en que tengo el componente aunque actualice la tabla en el padre, el hijo nunca tomara el cambio y mantendrá el estado inicial de esta.

Cree un ejemplo en para entender esto:

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Table from "./components/table";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [dataTableParent, setDataTableParent] = useState([]);
  const [listPage, setPageList] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
    console.log("useEffect list: ", list);
  }, [JSON.stringify(list)]);

  const updateList = () => {
    console.log("list after update: ", list);
    setList({
      ...list,
      number: "+1-541-754-3010"
    });
  };

  const createTable = () => {
    let data = [];
    data.push([
      "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Maria Anders",
      <button onClick={() => printList(list)}>Print list</button>
    ]);

    setDataTableParent(data);
  };

  const destroyTable = () => {
    let data = [];
    setDataTableParent(data);
  };

  const printList = (listTable) => {
    console.log("list parent: ", list);
    console.log("list child: ", listTable);
    setPageList(listTable.number);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Version °1</h1>
      <button onClick={updateList}>Update list</button>
      <button onClick={createTable}>Create table</button>
      <button onClick={destroyTable}>Destroy table</button>
      <Table
        dataTableParent={dataTableParent}
        theadThTable={[
          ["class-table", "Company"],
          ["class-table", "Contact"],
          ["class-table", "List"]
        ]}
      />
      <br></br>
      <p>list: {listPage}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**table.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles.css";

const Table = (props) => {
  const { dataTableParent, theadThTable } = props;
  const [dataTable, setDataTable] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
    setDataTable(dataTableParent);
  }, [JSON.stringify(dataTableParent)]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {theadThTable.map((element, index) => {
              return <th key={index}>{element[1]}</th>;
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {dataTable.map((element, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                {element.map((trElement, index) => {
                  return <td key={index}>{trElement}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (
    JSON.stringify(prevProps.dataTableParent) !==
      JSON.stringify(nextProps.dataTableParent) ||
    JSON.stringify(prevProps.theadThTable) !==
      JSON.stringify(nextProps.theadThTable)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

export default React.memo(Table, areEqual);
```

[image: Edit new]

En este ejemplo, si presionas "update list", luego "create table" y presionas el boton "print list" muestra los datos sin problema, pero, si creas la tabla antes de actualizar la lista, la tabla se creara sin esta y al presionar "print list" no tendrá los datos de la lista.

Una posibilidad es destruir la tabla y actualizar la lista para obtener los datos de esta, pero esto requiere eliminar una funcionalidad de paginación que tengo. Actualmente al crear la tabla consulta todos los datos de la lista antes de crearla y este comportamiento genera una consulta muy grande para una empresa.

Alguien me puede aconsejar como mejorarlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué es específicamente lo que estás buscando hacer? ¿Que las columnas `Company`, `Contact` y `List` de la tabla desaparezcan si no tienen datos?

Comment: Este es un ejemplo de la situación, mi objetivo es que la List este disponible cuando se necesite. Te explico que creo que sucede "Es mi punto de vista".

Comment: Cuando renderiza la tabla, guarda datos de forma temporal del componente padre, por eso ves 2 console.log, uno que envió la tabla y el otro le pertenece al padre, el problema es, si actualiza la lista el useEffec del list funciona correctamente, aunque si ejecutas print list, la lista del padre esta vacía y mantiene los datos antiguos. Esto me sucedió también con un select y un input. Aunque una solución que encontré fue envolver todo en un componente de clase y este problema se soluciona. Lo malo es que tengo que actualizar todo el proyecto para este objetivo